# Deploying a MERN app to render.com with one main folder structure - not separate front and back

Tags: deployment, mern, render.com

I have a MERN app that I would like to deploy to render.com. I just have 2 quick questions:

1. Of all the tutorials that I have watched, they all have separate github repos - 1 for the frontend, 1 for the backend. So on render.com, they can simply choose the frontend or the backend repo when they want to deploy. However, my folder structure is not like this - mine is one main github repo, and inside that repo, there is 1 frontend folder and 1 backend folder. How do I go about solving this?
2. When I give render.com (or heroku, netlify, etc.) access to my github account, is it safe? Does this mean they will be able to read and change stuff in my github account?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3):

My repo has the same structure as yours, one frontend folder and one backend folder.

1. You need to create a new **Web Service** for your backend folder. When creating a new web service, just set the *Root Directory* to *backend*. When you're done with the other fields and deployed your backend, create a **Static Site** for your frontend. Set the root directory of your static site to *frontend*. Set *Publish Directory* to *build*.
2. Probably safe but I'm new to the service as well. I believe they are only using that to be able to pull your repositories so that you can select them on Render. And also, of course, for auto or manual deployment.